# How to adjust the ordering of labels in the default legend in ggplot2 so that it corresponds to the order in the data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I am plotting a forest plot in ggplot2 and am having issues with the ordering of the labels in the legend matching the order of the labels in the data set. Here is my code below.

### data code

```
    d<-data.frame(x=c("Co-K(W) N=720", "IH-K(W) N=67", "IF-K(W) N=198", "CO-K(B)N=78", "IH-K(B) N=13", "CO=A(W) N=874","D-Sco Ad(W) N=346","DR-Ad (W) N=892","CE_A(W) N=274","CO-Ad(B) N=66","D-So Ad(B) N=215","DR-Ad(B) N=123","CE-Ad(B) N=79"),
y = rnorm(13, 0, 0.1))

d <- transform(d, ylo = y-1/13, yhi=y+1/13)
d$x <- factor(d$x, levels=rev(d$x)) # reverse ordering
```

### forest plot code

```
credplot.gg <- function(d){
# d is a data frame with 4 columns
# d$x gives variable names
# d$y gives center point
# d$ylo gives lower limits
# d$yhi gives upper limits
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ylo, ymax=yhi,group=x,colour=x,)) +
    geom_pointrange(size=1) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_color_discrete(name="Sample") + 
    coord_flip() +
    theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill='cornsilk2')) +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=0.5))) +
    geom_hline(aes(x=0), colour = 'red', lty=2) +
    xlab('Cohort') + ylab('CI') + ggtitle('Forest Plot')
return(p)
}
credplot.gg(d)
```

This is what I get. As you can see the labels on the y axis matches the labels in the order that it is in the data. However, it is not the same order in the legend. I'm not sure how to correct this. This is my first time creating a plot in ggplot2. Any feedback is well appreciated.Thanks in advanced

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice plot, especially for a first `ggplot`! I've not tested, but I think all you need is to add `reverse=TRUE` inside your `colour`'s `guide_legend`(found this in the [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/)).

If I were to make one more comment, I'd say that ordering your vertical factor by numeric value often makes comparisons easier when alphabetical order isn't particularly meaningful. (Though maybe your alpha order is meaningful.)